# Finding a triangle with max perimeter on a convex curve

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\Gamma$ be a convex curve, show that there exist three points like $A,B,C$ on $\Gamma$ such that the perimeter of $\Delta ABC$ is maximum.

I have no idea how should I start figuring out this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Closed curve? If not the problem is false...

Comment: This $\Gamma$ need not be a convex curve. Any compact set $\Gamma\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ will do.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter would you please explain more to help me find out what to do?

Comment: @vvnitram it's not mentioned in the text in front of me that the curve is closed, but I guess yes it has to be. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set
$$K:=\{(a,b,c)\in{\mathbb R}^6\>|\>a,b,c\in\Gamma\}$$
is compact. Therefore the continuous function
$$f(a,b,c):=|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a|$$
assumes a global maximum on $K$.

Comment: Thank you, sir! so it holds even for n-sided polygons as well, good.